# How to use media queries in IE 8

Tags: css, media-queries

My website content is not clearly visible at 1024 x768 resolution, the rest is working fine. What can I do?

Comment: Can you show how it looks like? Or provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for CSS3 Media Queries. This script emulates media queries for browsers that do not support it natively.

http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: hey Albin thanks..  i have used media queries in my site but in IE 8 its not working  so i want solution for iE 8

Comment: Ok, but this is how you use media queries in IE 8. What this script does is giving compatibility to the browsers that do not offer it, like IE7, IE8 and so on. All you need to do is to include the javascript file in your document and it should load for the browsers that do not have support for the regular css3 media queries.

Comment: no problems! please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: hey what i need to do is just adding that js file to my website?

Comment: u gave my that link mediaqueries.js where i found that file ,,that js file i added to my website but its not working,,,its really pissing me off!

Comment: Put up a new question on here describing the problem. Remember to supply some example code. It makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: hey albin now i used respond.js .This is the file which when we add to our website, automatically applies media queiries for IE, which we  write for chrome ,firefox n safari ....